# Ao chamar um iframe dentro de um arquivo .php, como enviar uma variável e recebê-la na página puxada pelo iframe?

Tags: php, javascript, html, variáveis, iframe

Tenho uma página index.php que contém o seguinte script:

```
<html>

//cabeçalho...

<div id="conteudo"> 
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">


$(this).on('load',function(){

    var dadosLink = 'nada';
    var mercado = 'nada';
    $.ajax({

        url:'conteudo.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data:{ dados:dadosLink,
                mercado:mercado
                 },
        success: function(data)
            {

            $("#conteudo").html(data);

            }, 

            error: function(data)

            {
            $("#conteudo").html(data);
                }

    });

    });


</html>

  </script>
```

Esta página envia os dados das variáveis *dadosLink* e *mercado* para o arquivo conteúdo.php

Segue o arquivo conteúdo.php:

```
<?php require_once('Connections/Gymo.php'); 

$aba = $_POST['dados'];
$mercado = $_POST['mercado'];

if  ($aba == "nada"){
echo '

<IFRAME name=Destaques src="mercadoria.php" frameBorder=0 style="overflow: scroll; height: 100vh; width: 100vw;"  scrolling=no>
<div align="center"></div>
</IFRAME>


';}
```

E então o conteudo.php pega o conteúdo da página mercadoria.php e envia para a div "conteudo" da página index.php.

Segue minha tentativa em mercadoria.php:

```
<?php
    //Incluir a conexão com banco de dados
    include_once('Connections/Gymo.php');

    //Recuperar o valor da palavra
    $setor = "alimento";
    $mercado= "dia";
    $mercado=$mercado;
    //Pesquisar no banco de dados nome do curso referente a palavra digitada pelo usuário
    $id= "SELECT id FROM $mercado";
    $setor = "
    SELECT * FROM banco_fotos
  INNER JOIN $mercado ON `$mercado`.`id` = `banco_fotos`.`id` 
  where banco_fotos.setor like '%$setor%'

    ";

    $resultado_setor = mysql_query($setor, $Gymo);

        while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado_setor)){

            echo''.$rows['descrp'].''.$rows['de'].''.$rows['por'].;} ?>
```

Enfim, a dúvida:

Como faço para que a página mercadoria.php receba as variáveis que estão declaradas na conteudo.php ($mercado e $aba)?

Pois o navegador informa todas as vezes que as variáveis $setor e $mercado de mercadoria.php não estão declaradas!

Tenho tentado fatidicamente encontrar esta solução há dias, mas não consigo!

Tentei também usar este iframe na conteudo.php, para tentar recuperar o atributo id e name na mercadoria.php, porém também não consegui:

```
<IFRAME name=Destaques src="mercadoria.php" id="'.$aba.'" name="'. $mercado .'""frameBorder=0 style="overflow: scroll; height: 100vh; width: 100vw;"  scrolling=no>
<div align="center"></div>
</IFRAME>
```

Existe uma solução pra isso?

Comment: Pra fazer essa troca de informações entre iframe e a página-mãe, precisa ser em javascript ou jquery.

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário. Poderia me indicar como isso é feito, ou onde eu posso descobrir como fazer isso? Por favor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Passe pelo método GET**  `src=\"mercadoria.php?dados=".$aba."&mercado=".$mercado."\`

```
if  ($aba == "nada"){
echo "

<IFRAME name=Destaques frameBorder=0 style=\"overflow: scroll; height: 100vh; width: 100vw;\"  scrolling=no src=\"mercadoria.php?dados=".$aba."&mercado=".$mercado."\" >
<div align=\"center\"></div>
</IFRAME>


";}
```

**Pagina mercadoria**

```
$aba = $_GET['dados'];
$mercado = $_GET['mercado'];
```

Comment: O exemplo está dado na resposta. Passam o valor de suas variáveis pela URL `src=\"mercadoria.php?dados=".$aba."&mercado=".$mercado."\`

Comment: Realmente funcionou! Obrigado mesmo! Quebrei a cabeça por tanto tempo!

Comment: Aproveitando o post: existe uma maneira de eu usar este src para enviar a variável de php para php durante um include?

Comment: @GuilhermeSilvadeOliveira sinceramente não consegui entender o cenário dessa nova situação do include, talvez uma nova pergunta com esse novo cenário seria mais esclarecedor